# Line numbering: stick with linum or nlinum?

Tags: linum-mode

I see that both `linum` and `nlinum` are actively maintained: one is built-in, another recently had a release.

With older Emacs version, `linum` used to be slow with a lot of folding in a buffer (e.g. in Org mode, and with `hs-minor-mode` in various source code modes). So I switched to `nlinum`.

Currently (on Emacs 15 and 26) I see that `linum` is sort of fast again, though maybe not always as smooth as `nlinum`.

Is there a reason why I should stick to one of them from *maintainability* POV? That is, does one of them obsolete, or is going to obsolete, another?

Comment: You might want to check out `display-line-numbers-mode` in recent Emacs versions. It uses code implemented in C, so it might be faster than both, and it ships with Emacs, so there will be an incentive to maintain it.

Comment: Not a great question for emacs.SE, I think. Discussions of what different people prefer and why is better for something like Reddit. Emacs.SE is looking for specific Q&A, and especially how-to Q&A.

Comment: @Drew: sorry about that. My question was not about preference, but about status, e.g. whether either of the packages is becoming obsoleted with recent Emacs development. It appears that both are!

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: Make it an answer please, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just a general comment, "is builtin" doesn't necessarily imply "actively maintained". See `perl-mode`, or CEDET for counterexamples.

Comment: [It seems that Emacs 29.1 has deprecated linum-mode.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78369/5165)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intention behind `nlinum.el` was to obsolete `linum.el` but it turns out that some customizations of `linum.el` can't really be adapted to `nlinum.el` (mostly the "relative line numbers").

Also the new `display-line-numbers-mode` in Emacs-26 aims to obsolete both of those.  But again, some customizations of `nlinum.el` and `linum.el` can't be adapted to `display-line-numbers-mode`.

Of the three, I think `linum.el` is the least maintained one and will probably be the first to be officially obsoleted.  But all three are likely to still be around for many years.