# What to use instead of linum-mode in Emacs 29?

Tags: linum-mode, emacs-29

It seems that Emacs 29.1 has deprecated linum-mode. I haven't found a replacement yet. On ELPA I see nlinum-mode, but that seems to use linum, too. So what is the official replacement?

Comment: If you take a look at `linum.el`, you will see "*Consider using **native line numbers** instead: `M-x display-line-numbers-mode`*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> in Emacs 29 and <kbd>C-s</kbd> for `linum` to easily find [this news](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=emacs-29&id=ef8838c3a5f041769f72758b831eb3fa7a130fb9#n493):

```
** The linum.el library is now obsolete.
We recommend using either the built-in 'display-line-numbers-mode', or
the 'nlinum' package from GNU ELPA instead.  The former has better
performance, but the latter is closer to a drop-in replacement.

1. To use 'display-line-numbers-mode', add something like this to your
   init file:

    (global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
    ;; Alternatively, to use it only in programming modes:
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)

2. To use 'nlinum', add this to your Init file:

    (package-install 'nlinum)
    (global-nlinum-mode 1)
    ;; Alternatively, to use it only in programming modes:
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'nlinum-mode)

3. To continue using the obsolete package 'linum', add this line to
   your Init file, in addition to any existing customizations:

    (require 'linum)
```

The fast/efficient `display-line-numbers-mode` has been included [since Emacs 26.1](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS.26#n565).

Comment: (perhaps) off-topic: "*using either the built-in `display-line-numbers-mode`, or the `nlinum` package from GNU ELPA*" -- so we can display both absolute and relative line numbers at the same time by *using both packages*.

Comment: Thank you especially for the hint to look at the news. I forgot that that's a thing!

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for the detailed submission